# How to split the array value in PHP?

Tags: php

This is my array value

```
Array (
    [0] => c:C
    [1] => cpp:CPP
    [2] => java:Java
)
```

Now I need to split the each index value like,

```
c C 
cpp CPP
java Java
```

How to do that?
let's assume it in a for loop, for each loop index value, I need to split the value into two parts.

Comment: `print_r(explode(':', $value));`?

Comment: If you need it as a string (and not as an array), you can replace colons by a space. `str_replace(":", " ", $value)`

Answer (score 1):

Use explode http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php:

```
$array = (
    0 => "c:C",
    1 => "cpp:CPP",
    2 => "java:Java",
);
foreach ($array as $values) {
    var_dump(explode(":", $values));
    // gives you an array like 0 => c, 1 => C
}
```

Comment: Thanq... @natheriel